# VBA Code to enter formula in column b when column a is populated

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I have a spreadsheet with a tab for each month. When a customer account number is entered into column a, I want a vlookup formula to be entered into column b, directly next to the cell in column a where the customer number was entered.

I have already set the sheets up with the vlookup formulas entered into the adjacent cells, but the sheet has become so big that the program has started to lag when the user enters data in column a. Now I am trying to reduce the size of the spreadsheet by setting up a vba code to enter this vlookup only when the cell in column a actually has data in it.

I have even tried creating a macro that will do this, and it works great, except my co-workers who use this sheet are VERY basic computer users, and it complicates things if they have to "do" anything to make the formula run.

Comment: Use the `Worksheet_Change` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I am actually brand new to VBA and am unsure how to write the code. I have tried many times today to find a code that basically says "If you type in a cell in column a, the adjacent cell in column b will run 'this vlookup'"  Unfortunately, I am at home and don't have the exact vlookup formula on my computer at home. Do you know of a code I could use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the worksheet's `_Change` event handler to do things, based on changes in the worksheet.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)

    'Prevent infinite loops by disabling event procedures
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'Make sure that at least one cell in selection is in column A:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Call MyMacro(Target)

    'Turn the event procedures back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In any module, put the sub that will actually *do* the dirty-work. This is a preference of mine, rathr than trying to cram *everything* in to the `_Change` event handler, I simply parse the Target and hand it off to the appropriate subroutine.

```
Sub MyMacro(rng as Range)

Dim cl as Range

For each cl in rng.Cells
    '## Make sure we're dealing with column A only:
    If cl.Column = 1 Then
        '## Insert a formula in the adjacent cell (column B)
        cl.Offset(0,1).Formula = "=Vlookup(..."

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I encountered a code earlier today that called for mymacro. I tried entering this just now, but I think I must be doing it wrong... I made a 'mock' spreadsheet to use while I'm at home to try to get this right so I can email it to myself at work. I opened the VBA screen for the worksheet I am working in and entered the first part of the code you posted. when I am finished and I press F5, I get a box that looks like it wants me to select a macro, but nothing is listed there

Comment: You can't run an event procedure from F5. It will run any time a cell value changes in the worksheet, but the formula will only write to column b. I'm sorry I don't have the time to teach you all the nuances of VBA...